# How can I improve this EF query?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

C# on .NET 3.5 Framework

So, I'm trying to make an efficient query to find all emails to purge from my system. What should be purged are emails that have been attempted (Datetime column LastAttempted is not null) and the # of days to retain (int column RetentionDays) has elapsed. This works, but I know it's pulling everything back and filtering in memory.

This is what I have right now

```
        var emails = dbContext.Emails
            .Where(x => x.LastAttempted.HasValue == true)
            .ToList()
            .Where(x => ((DateTime)x.LastAttempted).AddDays(x.RetentionDays) <= DateTime.Now);
```

How can I update this so it only pull the records I'm caring about from SQL Server?

Comment: It would be *"more efficient* to delete the records in a single query rather than pull them *then* delete them (assuming that's what you are trying to do).

Comment: I know I could call a stored proc and delete them, but I'm trying to better learn EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `EntityFunctions.AddDays` to add days to a `DateTime` in an EF query.

```
var emails = dbContext.Emails
    .Where(x => x.LastAttempted.HasValue &&
        EntityFunctions.AddDays(x.LastAttempted, x.RetentionDays) 
        <= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: I think this was introduced in .NET 4.0 Framework. Is there a way native to the .NET 3.5 Framework?

Answer (score 1):

This part of query:

```
dbContext.Emails
         .Where(x => x.LastAttempted.HasValue == true)
         .ToList();
```

will be executed in the sql server and an in memory collection will be returned, when ToList is called.

Then the last part of your query:

```
.Where(x => 
    ((DateTime)x.LastAttempted).AddDays(x.RetentionDays) <= DateTime.Now);
```

will be executed in the items of the above mentioned in memory collection.

So the problem relies on the last part of your query. You could avoid this using the method `AddDays` of `EntityFunctions` and avoid making the second filtering in the in memory collection. This can be done like below:

```
dbContext.Emails
         .Where(x => x.LastAttempted.HasValue == true &&
             EntityFunctions.AddDays(x.LastAttempted, x.RetentionDays) 
                 <= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Yes, he acknowledges this *in the question*.  He's asking how to not do this and execute the filtering on the database.

Comment: @Servy I just wanted to point out step by step where is the problem. I intended so, because reading this *This works, but I know it's pulling everything back and filtering in memory.*, I wasn't sure if the OP had realized where the problem exactly was.

Comment: Again, he *specifically* mentioned that in the question.  That is not an answer, it's just repeating the question back at him.

Answer (score 0):

Move ToList() at the end of the query

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var emails = dbContext.Emails
.Where(x => x.LastAttempted.HasValue && 
    EntityFunctions.AddDays((DateTime)x.LastAttempted, x.RetentionDays) <= now).
    ToList();
```

Comment: EF won't be able to translate this

Comment: Beat me to it. Well played.

Comment: I would also remove "that == true" and replace DateTime.Now with DateTime.Today to optimize the cosmetics too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always query the database directly, like this:

```
var items = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Email>("select * from Emails where LastAttempted Is Not Null And LastAttempted + RetentionDaya >= GetDate()", new SqlParameter[0]);
```

**NOTE:** I made some guesses with respect to your entity, table, and column names.